# For maximum security is it best to link OpenSSL libraries statically or dynamically?

Tags: openssl, aslr

When linking to OpenSSL (or other cryptographic libraries) would it be more secure to use a shared library and have address space layout randomization, or to use a static library and not have ASLR?

Comment: You will also want to take into account that OpenSSL releases security fixes noticeably regularly.  Static linking will need to be repeated, dynamic linking will benefit from simpler OS patch + process restart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ASLR and such things are ways to try to cope with consequences of a buffer overflow -- they are an hide&seek game so that attackers find it harder to turn a buffer overflow into remote code execution. For proper security, it is better to make it so that buffer overflows don't occur in the first place.

... and for that, dynamic linking is better. The reason is the following: it would be inordinately optimistic to believe that any given piece of code written in C does not have any buffer overflow (especially OpenSSL, which has a rather long history on that subject). Thus, the best that you can do is to be able to *promptly* fix known security holes by replacing the faulty part. If you use dynamic linking, this is easy: just replace the DLL, and be done with it. If the DLL is provided by the OS (the normal case in Linux systems) then this will be done naturally when you apply security updates from the OS vendor. However, if you use static linking, then the patches won't make it into your application until you recompile (or at least relink) that specific application with the patched OpenSSL.

In practice, static linking means that security fixes on the library will take longer to be applied to the application -- or, more often than not, won't be applied at all. This is bad. Therefore, **use dynamic linking**.

Comment: "it would be inordinately optimistic to believe that any given piece of code written in C does not have any buffer overflow" Not if the person writing it is competent and knows how to test things. But in the general case, yes. I suppose that's right. Competence is one thing I've had to learn never to assume...

Comment: There is reputedly only _one_ software without bugs (Metafont, written by Donald Knuth). It is possible to write safe C code by being careful; but, apparently, it is not humanly possible to be sufficiently careful throughout the whole development of any significant piece of software. However, competent programmers can be good at leaving _few_ bugs, and fixing them promptly when detected. Which is enough in practice, as long as the patch installation process is sleek and slight (hence dynamic linking).

Comment: Why more research money hasn't been put into cloning Donald Knuth I will never understand.

Comment: Linux uses shared objects (`.so` files), not DLLs.

Comment: @TomLeek There are a few examples of software "without bugs". Primarily formally verified (mathematically proven correct) software like miTLS, HTTP.sys, or seL4. The specific classes of bugs which they are proven to be free of differs, for example seL4 does not guarantee freedom from side-channel attacks, though I believe that is being worked on. And of course, changing even a single line of code in a formally verified project can violate the entire proof (which is why HTTP.sys was hit with an RCE involving its then-recently-added non-verified caching layer).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "mathematically proven correct". You can mathematically prove the correctness of an algorithm but one is the theory and another is the implementation. I doubt that a bug-free application really exists but if it does how can you prove "mathematically" that there is 0 probability (exactly 0 probability) to came across a bug while the application is running ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I just wanted to throw in some opinions in case anyone else passes by. The accepted answer is accurate in that static linking makes it more difficult to do an in-place upgrade. For example, if you're using OpenSSL with your app, you could just deploy the new libcrypto.dll (assuming it's backward compatible with your app) over the old DLL, and you'll be good.

However, in regard to exploits and other nasty stuff, I would argue static linking is a little more secure. Basically, there's no DLL external to your application that can be swapped with a tainted version of the same DLL or even a shim (DLL proxy and the like...)

Additionally, and this isn't really an argument against either, but if your external library has an exploit neither static or dynamic is going to be safer as it's exploited at run-time when it's already linked in to your application.

I agree with their advice on making it easier to match current OpenSSL versions and for the most part would suggest dynamic linking, but you know your application best, and since the original question asked which is safer (while deployed on a box, I assume), you should also think about tampering.

Comment: It's easy to prevent a tainted version of a library from being linked. On Linux at least, the paths where applications search for libraries can only be written to by root. The only way to override that requires setting an environmental variable, and if an attacker controls your environment, you've already lost. Tampering is absolutely **not** a valid reason to use static linking, and it is **useless** as an integrity measure. Giving up efficient upgrades and ASLR for snake-oil is a terrible idea.

Comment: Sure, it's security through obscurity. Also, I should have specified, my comment is for Windows, where you application could be installed in an unprivileged user accessible directory. Not everyone is doing in-place upgrades. 

A better solution to check for tampering with dynamic linking could be to check the hash against a known good of your local lib/dll/so before you load them, if you want to take it up a notch.

Comment: If an application is in an unprivileged directory, then even if it's static, it can be tampered with. Security through obscurity is not security.

Comment: It's still easier to mess  with an external dependency than reverse a binary and exploit. I could just swap your new lib with an older, vulnerable one that I can exploit. It makes it a little harder to get the cheese, is my point.

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. Switching with a malicious library means you need to understand the library's ABI. Switching to an older one may break the ABI and still requires expertise in exploitation. Someone who can exploit _any_ library is not so clueless that they do not know how to trivially use a universal malicious wrapper on the executable. Your advice just isn't grounded in reality. Your assumptions are off.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to look up that info without any reversing, especially if the DLL/SO has the version in the name. For example, libcrypt-1_0-x64.dll. Now we know they use openssl and the version. The only reason I've cared to rebut this far is from experience, if you think that's fantasy, fine just ignore it, but it's definitely not as hard as you think (again, mostly referring to windows). I'll leave this here [link](https://blog.netspi.com/testing-applications-for-dll-preloading-vulnerabilities/)

Comment: Yes it is trivial, but it's still not something a script kiddie could do. Putting a binary in a wrapper/packer however _is_ something they could do. You're suggesting that modifying a binary into maliciousness is harder than modifying a library, which is patently false. I've been trying to think of a threat model where static linking is more secure, and all I can think of is _FLUSH+FLUSH_-style side-channel attacks against shared pages in memory, which is a very narrow situation. Otherwise you're relying on someone being too dumb to use a packer, but smart enough to understand library ABI.

Comment: As for your link, that requires changing either the environment, or an unprivileged path, in which case there are plenty of (easier) ways to compromise an application even if it is statically linked. Can you give me _any_ situation in which someone who is not clever enough to use a freeware packer will be able to exploit a dynamically linked executable but not a statically linked one? Also not to nitpick but I think _libcrypt_ is a libc thing, _libcrypto_ is OpenSSL (even in Windows).

Comment: There are literally instructions on that site how to do it using metasploit (a favorite among scriptkiddies), and it's the first site that popped up from a google search. Yes, if you read up in my first reply, the "attacker" needs access to a dir in the load path, which is not that uncommon in Windows unless good policy and access controls are in place (sadly, pretty rare). Thanks for the correction, yes I meant libcrypto in that example. My point remains, if an application depends on loading external DLLs, the attack surface is larger.

Comment: You are still relying on security through obscurity, which has no place on Sec.SE. You are giving up several important security benefits (which have deterministic properties) for obscurity which is so easy to bypass that even a script kiddie who doesn't know how to use metasploit or don't care to read the documentation can do it (as packers are far easier to use than metasploit - they can even come with their own flashy GUIs). I mean this is about as beneficial to security as marking your executables hidden or replacing the folder icon with the IE icon (except those don't _reduce_ security).

Comment: @forest, tampering with a binary is more difficult than copy/pasting a DLL, even if you have a packer doing all the work for you. Declaring this isn't a security issue and it doesn't belong on SecSE baffles me. Here are some more links about static vs dynamic linking, including security issues. [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/tqudb/are_go_binaries_really_entirely_statically_linked/)  and one of the links from the reddit thread that I think has a good explanation as well [http://harmful.cat-v.org/](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/dynamic-linking/)

Comment: Copy and pasting a DLL requires at the very least that you have a compatible ABI. You do not need to "tamper" with a binary to make it malicious. A packer does that all for you. As for the cat-v page, that's primarily talking about the perf impact (which exists, but is far lesser than it was when that was written). Their "security" concerns are not voiced at all, making it an irrelevant link. The links at the bottom in regards to `ldd(1)` being a security issue is just silly. Sysadmins who do not know how `ldd` works does not make dynamic linking insecure.

Comment: Here's a more recent one: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2389418/secure-loading-of-libraries-to-prevent-dll-preloading-attacks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2389418/secure-loading-of-libraries-to-prevent-dll-preloading-attacks), These attacks are avoided by statically linking. Call it obscurity or hiding, but it's making it harder for a would-be attacker to gain a foothold in a running process.

Comment: It makes it slightly harder to attack a process in one way, and makes it significantly easier to attack it in other ways. I mean sure, you could even argue that the dynamic linker and `dlsym()` and friends increase attack surface, but that doesn't change the fact that, overall, dynamic linking provides superior security at the potential expense of making one specific type of attack slightly harder. I mean yeah, I agree that it's security through obscurity, and that's the primary thing I object to. Security through obscurity is _not security_.

Comment: @chanchos: Thanks for sharing your point of view in a constructive way and through some useful links. I was particularly interested in this specific case of security vulnerability, the fact that anybody can recompile libcrypto with printf spread all over the code, allowing the printing of any key and decrypted cypher of a specific binary.

Comment: @Sdra Anyone can recompile it, but not just anyone can make an application use it. If they have the level of privilege to make your application use it, they can also just directly modify your application (which is much worse).

Comment: @forest: OpenSSL on Unix is canonically libssl and libcrypto .a/so/sl/dylib/etc often plus versions(s), but on Windows for very hysterical raisins it is ssleay32 and libeay32 .dll/lib (even on Win64!). Which doesn't matter to any vuln(s), of course.